# Reposition selector using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using Flexbox which is just a brilliant CSS feature, I read somewhere that it could reposition selectors. To save it being done if you don't have the option to do it in HTML or Javascript.

Would it be possible to put these in a different order say 1,4,3,2 using Flexbox?

```
    <div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="link1">First Menu Item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link2">Second Menu Item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link3">Third Menu Item</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link4">Fourth Menu Item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    #cssmenu ul {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fewk5o7d/

Answer (score 3):

Sure...simple, using the `order` property available to us under flexbox.

[**Order @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

> The CSS order property specifies the order used to lay out flex items in their flex container. Elements are laid out in the ascending order of the order value. Elements with the same order value are laid out in the order in which they appear in the source code.

By default the flex-items have an `order` value of 0 so it's just a matter of re-arranging them

```css
        #cssmenu ul {
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: space-around;
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        li:nth-child(2) {
          order: 2
        }
        li:nth-child(3) {
          order: 3
        }
        li:nth-child(2) {
          order: 4
        }
```

```html
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link1">First Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link2">Second Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link3">Third Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link4">Fourth Menu Item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note...this is purely a **visual** effect...the DOM order remains the same.

Comment: So I can just set one, for example setting the 4th selector to be order 1 only that would push all the others along giving 4,1,2,3

Comment: Not quite...the order property only moves the item itself, it doesn't *push* the others. Since, in your second example, you need to move the 4th item in front of the others you need to use an `order` value lower than their default of `0`...so `order:-1` works - https://jsfiddle.net/mad3cszc/